# Reproject Data on to WRF grid

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, modis, wrf-model

I have MODIS data EVI and LSWI which I want to fit to WRF grid  which in LCC projection system, I can read specification using CEN_LON, LAT1, LAT2. Based on that I have reprojected my TIFF files using command:

```
gdalwarp -of netCDF -geoloc -t_srs '+proj=lcc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=81.57401  +lat_1=24.762 +lat_2=24.762 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +units=m +no_defs' -tr 20000 20000 -r average -srcnodata -32768 EVI_2015001_clip.tif EVI_2015001_lcc.nc
```

to WRF grid system. But now I want the data to be remapped properly on to WRF grid. How can I do this?

There is an option using NCL for regridding on curvilinear grids using ESMF. But got that I need to have 2d lat lon values of source file. which gdal warp is not producing. It is just giving x and y projected values in meters.

Any solution?